# Does this relay's LED circuit work as a flyback diode?

Tags: relay

I'm looking to use a relay to provide on/off control to a 3D printer AC bed.

I have a [Releco C10-A10X](https://www.comatreleco.com/wp-content/uploads/cr-prod/cr-prod-doc/EN_DAT_CAT_C10-A1x_00001.pdf) which for the 5 V version has an LED and a rectifier bridge.

The wiring diagram for the relay (coil) looks like this:

[image]

I think the LED will drain the relay coil when the coil is disconnected and so act as a flyback diode but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to link to the relay's datasheet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It won't exactly act as a flyback diode, but it will have some effect.

**Note: It is *intended* to be used with an external flyback diode or other type of snubber so I am just addressing what happens if you *don't* do that.**

When the relay driver turns off (assuming you have no external diode or other type of clamp or snubber) the current that flowed to the coil will find its way through the bridge to the LED plus resistor. The voltage across the driver will rise to about Irelay * R where R is the series resistor. Let's assume the relay draws 50mA and the LED is 1mA with a 12V drive, so the series resistor is about 10K. The voltage across the driver will then spike to about 500V (plus the 12V supply plus the LED Vf minus two diode drops),. That number will be different depending on the relay coil current and the LED resistor (for example, if the LED current was 10mA the spike would be to only about 62V, which might be okay for some drivers and the relay would last longer because switching would be faster).

A secondary issue is that the LED sees a brief spike of approximately the nominal coil current. Probably not an issue in most cases.

The reason for the bridge is so that the user of the relay does not have to worry about the polarity of the input- the LED will still work. Nothing to do with flyback.

**TL;DR: Add suitable external protection for your driver.**

Answer (score 2):

Because of the resistor in series with the LED, this circuit will provide only mild transient suppression.

Answer (score 2):

> *I have a Releco C10-A10X which for the 5 V version has an LED and a
> rectifier bridge.*

There is no 5 volt coil version: -

[image]

The lowest voltage in the data sheet at DC is 12 volts nominal. The data sheet also specifies the coil voltage range: -

[image]

So, you need to guarantee that the minimum coil voltage is at least 80% of 12 volts i.e. 9.6 volts. This relay won't work at 5 volts.

However, if there is a 5 volt version you should make that data sheet available so that the LED current can be estimated and the effectiveness of it as a snubber can be determined.

Comment: Annoyingly on the Releco website the 5v Relay has a link to the datasheet that denies it exists...  However, I have measured mine and the resistance of the coil is 44ohms and the current draw at 5v is 125mA - does that help?

Comment: Not really; I work from data sheets and I use them to calculate extreme limit values so, what is needed is the data sheet for the 5 volt version @JMildenhall. I suppose if you assume the LED takes 20 mA then that would be half a stab at approximating an answer. But, that LED may not be able to take the full 125 mA so, you cannot rely on it as a snubber for anything other than 20 mA of those 125 mA. The remaining 105 mA may well make a big voltage splash.